# Can i use rain water for my aloe vera?

Tags: plant-health

I have just bought myself a Aleo vera plant for my room and i was wondering, could i collect rain water and use it to feed my Aleo vera? Or should i just feed it tap water? Im very worried about it.

Answer (score 1):

In many parts of the world where the soil is light and warm and the sun beats down for much of the day Aloe Vera is grown as an agricultural crop to supply the cosmetics market. Rain water is all they get in those circumstances except in really exceptional conditions, so rain water is good. Just make sure that your pot is well drained and the soil is allowed to dry out thoroughly between waterings. In most areas tap water is also good unless it has been heavily treated against hard water, chlorine and so on.

Rain water is preferred; pay attention to the surface it runs from - if it has accumulated gunk of various sorts allow it to wash off first and then collect the cleaner subsequent water.